# Visual Studio 2022/XLL SDK issue – debugger looking for exe file instead of xll

Tags: visual-studio, xll

I have used the latest (2013) Excel XLL SDK and VS 2022 Community version to successfully build and run the 64-bit sample Generic.XLL. An XLL is a C-language DLL with additional code for Excel add-in support. Generic.XLL makes 3 sample functions available in Excel. I built the project straight from the MS XLL SDK sample project solution file Generic.sln.

I am having trouble getting the debugger going. After inserting breakpoints and starting the debugger, I get the following error message:

“Unable to start program…. C:...file path…\GENERIC.exe’.     The system cannot find the specified file.”

Of course the debugger can’t find Generic.exe. The project solution does not build an EXE file, it builds the output file Generic.xll.

Why is the debugger looking for an EXE file instead of the XLL file? Any suggestions for how to get the VS 2022 debugger to open the output file with the correct XLL filename extension?

Please and thanks for looking! I am a newbie with VS 2022.

I have tried renaming the filename extension of the output xll file to exe before initiating debug, but I receive the same error message.

Comment: Excel.exe is the program the debugger needs to start. You can either add your xll name as an option to the Excel command line, or just open the xll from Excel once it is up & running. In the Project settings, go to Debugging under Configuration Properties. Then specify the full path to the Excel executable in the Command field (possibly `C:\Program Files\Microsoft Office\root\Office16\EXCEL.EXE` depending on where it is installed). Also in Configuration Properties / Advanced, change the "Target File Extension" to `.xll` ... if not already set to that.

Comment: Thank you for your response. The project settings are such that output file has the xll extension. I do understand that Excel has to open, but nonetheless the VS error message states it cannot open a Generic.exe file that this MS sample solution does not build. My understanding of how the debugger works is different. As I know it, with Excel closed I open the VS solution and start the debugger, which in turn starts Excel. I tried your suggestion of opening Excel and loading the add-in, it did not work, it did not start VS.

Comment: I am just trying your other suggestion now, sorry missed that earlier.

Comment: Your suggestion of adding C:\Program Files\Microsoft Office\root\Office16\EXCEL.EXE to the debug command path worked. Problem solved. Thank you.